# Develop an iPhone / iPad Reader app from scratch

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm developing a reader app for viewing and highlighting proprietary format documents. The documents are 2D. (Might add some cool page flip effects) The interface is similar to that of mobile safari.  I have no prior experience with iOS development. Could you guys point me to the right direction? (Things I need to consider, tutorials, sample projects...) THX

Comment: What existing programming experience do you have?  If you have done Objective-C before, you could probably get away with just the developer.apple.com docs.  If not, you'll ned a book about learning Objective-C.

Comment: have a lot of experience with JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

developer.apple.com - it will take you a VERY long way.  And then google whatever you need after that.

Comment: sorry, but without knowing you at all, this can't be answered.  small device programming is not the same as server side java - everything about it is different.  learn the platform, understand the GUI, grok the tools, everybody figures things out at a different pace.

Answer (score 0):

In itune U, you can download the 'iPhone Application Programming' course form Stanford University.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're a registered developer, Apple just made all of the videos and slides from last week's WWDC available for free at http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/.  There's an insane amount of very up-to-date info there.